# Can I assign a BaseUri to an XDocument?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

When I load an XML document from disk into an XDocument, that XDocument has a ready-only property BaseUri that contains the original XML document's location on disk.  In other words,

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\doc.xml");
Console.Out.WriteLine(doc.BaseUri);
// Outputs "file:///c:/temp/doc.xml"
```

If I create a new XDocument from scratch, it has no BaseUri.  For example:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("test"));
Console.Out.WriteLine(doc.BaseUri);
// Outputs nothing
```

Can I assign this new XDocument a BaseUri?  I'd like to be able to generate new documents, assign them names, and easily pass those names along with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading [LoadOptions.SetBaseUri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.loadoptions.aspx) it is apparent that LINQ to XML uses Annotations to achieve the setting of the `BaseUri` property. This is unfortunate as the annotation is of the internal type `System.Xml.Linq.BaseUriAnnotation`, which you do not have access to. My suggestion would be to perhaps set your own annotation which would use either its value or the value of `BaseUri` if it was not `null`.

```
public class MyBaseUriAnnotation
{
    public XObject XObject { get; private set; }

    private string baseUri = String.Empty;
    public string BaseUri
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.baseUri))
                return this.XObject.BaseUri;

            return this.baseUri;
        }

        set { this.baseUri = value; }
    }

    public MyBaseUriAnnotation(XObject xobject)
       : this(xobject, String.Empty)
    {
    }

    public MyBaseUriAnnotation(XObject xobject, string baseUri)
    {
        if (xobject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("xobject");
        this.XObject = xobject;
        this.baseUri = baseUri;
    }
}
```

You can then use a method to add the annotation to an `XDocument` you parse on your own:

```
public static XDocument XDocumentFromString(string baseUri, string xml)
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
    xdoc.AddAnnotation(new MyBaseUriAnnotation(xdoc, baseUri));
    return xdoc;
}
```

And then whenever you'd like to find the `BaseUri`, you could use an extension method to retrieve the correct `BaseUri`:

```
public static string FindBaseUri(this XObject xobject)
{
    if (xobject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(xobject);
    var baseUri = xobject.Annotation<MyBaseUriAnnotation>();
    return baseUri != null ? baseUri.BaseUri : xobject.BaseUri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of using an annotation.

Comment: You could also extend my example to search up the XObject hierarchy until it found a MyBaseUriAnnotation in order to behave identically to XObject.BaseUri.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, you can't easily do so. You can do it when you load with any `XmlReader`, if you set the appropriate option. This means you *could* write an extension method which saved it to a `MemoryStream` then loaded a new document from a custom class derived from `XmlTextReader` which overrode `BaseUri`. That would be pretty ugly though :(

Answer (score 4):

The ugly but the fastest way:

```
var doc = XElement.Parse(someXml);
doc.GetType()
         .GetMethod("SetBaseUri", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
         .Invoke(doc, new object[] { "some uri" });
```

Comment: Compared to trying to create a double value (one set by yourself, and one by the system, as in the original accepted answer), this is much, much better (provided you cache the methodinfo). Of course, it would be even better if Microsoft exposes this method publicly.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class CustomXmlDocument : XmlDocument
    {
        public string CustomBaseURL { get; set; }


        public override string BaseURI
        {
            get { return this.CustomBaseURL; }
        }
    }

CustomXmlDocument objXML=new CustomXmlDocument();
objXML.CustomBaseURL="BaseURI";
objXML.loadXml(xml document);
```