# XDocument File Name

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

Is there a way to retrieve XDocument saved path (file name) from the XDocument object itself?

I mean to get the saved path after I already saved the XDocument object. Something like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
xDoc.Save(@"C:\Temp\MyXmlDoc.xml");

string str = xDoc.SavedPath() // <== something like this
```

Comment: I don't understand why you cannot store the full file name in a variable and use it where you need it?

Comment: @Serghei: I don't believe the OP is ruling that out; they're just asking if that mechanism is already handled by the XDocument type rather than implementing their own solution from the start.

Comment: Hi Serghei, I just wondered if this property is available. I understand and accept your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an XDocument does not remember where it has been saved to.

You have to remember the path yourself, e.g.

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
string str = @"C:\Temp\MyXmlDoc.xml";
xDoc.Save(str);
```

Comment: Thank you, I already implemented this solution/ Just wanted to know if this property exists.

Comment: @RoiShabtai: Have a look at this: [Can I assign a BaseUri to an XDocument?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440023/can-i-assign-a-baseuri-to-an-xdocument)

Answer (score 6):

If you load the [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) from a file, the [`BaseUri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.baseuri.aspx) property will contain the file name. As stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.baseuri.aspx):

> Sometimes the XmlReader has the base
>   URI, and sometimes it does not. For
>   instance, when loading from a file,
>   the XmlReader knows the base URI, but
>   when reading from an XmlReader that
>   was created because of calling the
>   Parse method, there is no possibility
>   of the XmlReader reporting a base URI;
>   the XML was in a string.

However, this is not set when saving the document, only during load operations. Therefore, if you need to know the save path, you will need to store that independently of the `XDocument` instance when saving.